# How to manage third-party erlang applications?

Tags: erlang

How do you manage erlang applications that are not part of the Erlang/OTP release ? Where do you usually install them ? If you install them aside of Erlang/OTP release, how do you tell erlang VM where to look them up (Yes, I know about -pz flag but it seems to be a little awkward for me to use that flag when there are more than one third-party apps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the `ERL_LIBS` environment variable to point out where I have my applications installed.

See "Code Path" under http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html